# Can`t call command with variable on sh file using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, sh

I have the script on `centos 7` server for kill process by used id:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "killing services..."

kill -9 "$(lsof -t -i:3011)"
kill -9 "$(lsof -t -i:4011)"
```

Above script works fine when it is called from the server.

But my goal calls this file using `ssh` from my local machine like:

```
ssh xxx@xxx.x "sh ~/stopServices.sh"
```

But I git this error:

```
killing services...
/home/system/gepick-dev/stopDevServices.sh: line 5: lsof: command not found
/home/system/gepick-dev/stopDevServices.sh: line 5: kill: `': not a pid or valid job spec
/home/system/gepick-dev/stopDevServices.sh: line 6: lsof: command not found
/home/system/gepick-dev/stopDevServices.sh: line 6: kill: `': not a pid or valid job spec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install lsof on the remote server.

or  try to add the full path like /usr/sbin/lsof to your script or configure your PATH in the remote server if the binary is already installed

Comment: I already have it because this script working when I call it when logged to the server

Comment: then try to add the full path like /usr/sbin/lsof to your script or configure your PATH in the remote server

Comment: Yes it helped +1